# Laravel Self Recursive Relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently learning Laravel. I have a column in database called "Folder" and it has self-dependency. There might be multiple folders in a folder. I wanted to create an api with the structure shown in expected result. However, the result that I had gotten was as actual result.

[Expected and Actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZvUX.png)

Can someone please guide me to achieve the expected result? ***I don't want to show the children as parent.***

Below is my code implementation:

**Model**

```
class Folder extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The relationships that should always be loaded.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['inner_folders'];

    public function inner_folders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'folder_id')->with('inner_folders');
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'folder_id',
        'folder_name',
        'folder_attr',
        'image'
    ];
}
```

**Resource Collection**

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'folder_name' => $this->folder_name,
            'folder_attr' => $this->folder_attr,
            'image' => $this->image,
            'folder_id' => $this->folder_id,
            'inner_folders' => FolderResourceCollection::collection($this->whenLoaded('inner_folders'))
        ];
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $user_id = $request->input('user_id');
        return new FolderResource(Folder::where('user_id', $user_id)->get());
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change   ```$this->whenLoaded('inner_folders')``` to ```$this->inner_folders```

Comment: Thanks for your  reply. However, I am still getting the same result.